# Firestore Security Rules - Nested Collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

i am trying to create security rules for my firestore instance. here is the data structure and requirements of the collections.

**User Collection**

```
/users/{userId}
{
 id:userId
 isAdmin:bool
},
```

**News Collection**

```
/news/{docId}
{
 id:docId,
 userId:uid,
 viewCount:number,
 commentsCount:number,
 upVotes: number,
 comments: collection
}
```

**Comments Collection**

```
/news/comments/{commentId}
    {
     id:commentId,
     userId:uid,
    }
```

**Requirements for news Collection:**

Only Users with isAdmin flag set to true can create,update and delete this document except for the viewCount and commentsCount which can be updated if any of the following conditions meet.

1. any user authenticated or un authenticated view the document
2. if only authenticated user posted a comment

**Requirement for /news/{docId}/comments Collection:**

All Users authenticated or un authenticated can view the comments
Only Authenticated users can create comments.
Only User with uid == userId can delete or update the document

my effort so far.

```
  match /news/{docId}{  
    allow read;  
    //we need to improve the below statement  
    allow write: if Authenticated() && request.auth.uid == 'adminUserId';  
    match /comments/{commentId}{  
        allow read;  
        allow create: if Authenticated() && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.userId;  
        allow update,delete: if Authenticated() && request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId;  
    }  
  }
```

Comment: And what's your problem/question?

Comment: i want the news collection to be only written by admin but the commentCount field can be updated by any logged in user. how can do it?